# ref() with different behavior when using composition API / option API

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

How to replicate the same behavior from option api to composition api?
When the button is clicked, only the clicked element/component must be activated

(this.$refs.copy) behavior activates one component at a time inside the dom using option API

```html
<template>
  <button ref="copy" class="copy-button">
    <img v-if="state === 'copied'" src="/images/icons/verifiedCopy.svg" />
    <img v-else src="/images/icons/unverifiedCopy.svg" />
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import Clipboard from 'clipboard'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      state: 'init'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const copyCode = new Clipboard(this.$refs.copy, {
      target(trigger) {
        return trigger.parentElement?.previousElementSibling
      }
    })
    copyCode.on('success', (event) => {
      event.clearSelection()
      this.state = 'copied'
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.state = 'init'
      }, 2000)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Active 'ref()' behavior in all CopyButton components using composition api

```html
<template>
  <button ref="copy" class="copy-button">
    <img v-if="state === 'copied'" src="/images/icons/verifiedCopy.svg" />
    <img v-else src="/images/icons/unverifiedCopy.svg" />
  </button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Clipboard from 'clipboard'
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const state = useState(() => 'init')
const copy = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)

onMounted(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const copyCode = new Clipboard(copy.value!, {
      target(trigger) {
        return trigger.parentElement?.previousElementSibling!
      }
    })

    copyCode.on('success', (event) => {
      event.clearSelection()
      state.value = 'copied'
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        state.value = 'init'
      }, 2000)
    })
  }, 55)
})
</script>
```

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. What do you have with this? How does the behaviour differs from options api. A ref is used the way you use it. useState isn't shown in the question, it's a clear difference

Comment: This component
has the behavior of copying a block of code, I am adding this component dynamically and when there is more than one component of it, the composition API code triggers them all at once, but I need it to have the same behavior as the option API that triggers a component per click

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce the problem? Composition isn't supposed to cause such problem here

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the state, it appears to be shared across all CopyButton components.

I changed the declaration to `const state = ref('init')` and everything works as expected

```
<template>
  <button ref="copy" class="copy-button">
    <img v-if="state === 'copied'" src="/images/icons/verifiedCopy.svg" />
    <img v-else src="/images/icons/unverifiedCopy.svg" />
  </button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Clipboard from 'clipboard'

const state = ref('init')
const copy = ref<HTMLElement>()

onMounted(() => {
  {
    const copyCode = new Clipboard(copy.value!, {
      target(trigger) {
        return trigger.parentElement?.previousElementSibling!
      }
    })
    copyCode.on('success', (event) => {
      event.clearSelection()
      state.value = 'copied'
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        state.value = 'init'
      }, 2000)
    })
  }
})
</script>
```